# Android: Receive HTML page through intent

Tags: android, html, android-intent

I have enabled My App for the share via options in the HTML page. Now, I am trying to store the HTML page from where this was triggered in my sdcard. For this purpose, I was trying to use the intent contents.

I used the following for images and It worked like charm..

```
    Uri imageUri = (Uri) shareintent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
            Uri uri = (Uri) extras.getParcelable(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            InputStream is = cr.openInputStream(uri);
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is ,null, options);
```

Please can you give me an hint of how to save the HTML page in my sdcard?

Comment: I am not aware that browsers put the HTML page itself into the `ACTION_SEND` `Intent`. The URL for the page is given to you.

Comment: Ok. So, in which case, can i store a local copy of the url content somehow?

Comment: You are welcome to use the URL however you like, such as by downloading the page using `HttpUrlConnection`. Bear in mind that it may not be possible to download the page, as you will not have session cookies, authentication details, etc.

Answer (score 0):

within a WebView (a layout which allows opening webpages within your application...among other things) and using HttpClient.execute() or HttpClient.get() should do the trick for you.

Comment: Its not opened through my app. I am calling my app activity through the intent with the "share via" option..

Comment: If you're trying to save the content of an HTML page the easiest way is using a JavaScript interface which shows the HTML code.

Then using javascript use window.yourinterface.showHTML.  
Give me a moment and i'll see if i can find the tutorial I used when i created an application similar to this.

Comment: Found it faster than i thought, here ya go:
http://lexandera.com/2009/01/extracting-html-from-a-webview/